# Что такое дискриптор $this-> в php?

Tags: php

Что такое дискриптор $this-> в php? Объясните пожалуйста что он делает, где применяеться и какова его суть?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test {

     public $test = '123';

     public function testMethod2() {
          return '456';
     }

     public function testMethod() {
          echo $this->test;
          echo $this->testMethod2();
     }

}

$var = new Test();
$var->testMethod();
```

Как можно видеть из примера, `$this->` это обращение к другим переменным/функциям внутри класса. Но тут важно чтоб у это класса был экземпляр, если мы говорим о статических, то у них используется `self::`

```
class Test {

     public static $test = '123';

     public static function testMethod2() {
          return '456';
     }

     public static function testMethod() {
          echo self::$test;
          echo self::testMethod2();
     }

}

Test::testMethod();
```

Comment: @RovshanIbraqimov ваш вопрос исчерпан и он решен?

Comment: Конечно еще ответов не помешало б, но хоть что то понятно.

Comment: @RovshanIbraqimov всмысле хоть что-то? у него задача - доступ к объектам изнутри класса. Другого нет))) это как вопрос: сколько будет 2+2, тебе говорят - 4, а ты такой: ну вроде хоть что-то понятно, но не помешало-б еще ответов. ну хорошо, жди...

Comment: Понятно спасибо) Я тут новичок.

Comment: Я бы сделал несколько важных, на мой взгляд, правок.
1. `$this->` не есть обращение к другим функциям, `$this->` это обращение внутри объекта к самому себе.   
2. Если ваш класс наследует другой класс то `self`  возможно даст не то что вам нужно. Скорее нужно использовать `static`. Про позднее статическое связывание можно почитать [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)